# Vector for Function Values?

Tags: r

I have a function with a while loop that gives me back different values for every loop. How can I display the different values in one vector? Right now i have the function and its quite ok but for my exercse i need the values in vector and im not able to figure it out.

I already tried to do it with

```
print(paste("Lösungsvektor:", b))
```

but i don't know how i should implement the vector in to the function.

```
Collatz <- function(n) {
 while (n != 1) {
  print(n)
  if(n %% 2 == 0){
  n <- n/2
 }else{
  n <- n*3+1
  }
}
print(1)
}

Collatz(22)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your function doesn't actually return anything, just prints, so we need to fix that. What it returns is a vector that should be built as the while loop progresses. Here's one option:

```
Collatz <- function(n) {
     j<-2
     output<-n
     while (n != 1) {
         if(n %% 2 == 0){
             n <- n/2
         }else{
             n <- n*3+1
         }
     output[j]<-n
     j<-j+1
     }
     output
 }

 Collatz(22)
 [1] 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10  5 16  8  4  2  1
```

Comment: If performance issues are encountered, it may be worth preallocating space for `output`, although @iod's solution works fine for smaller `n`. [R Inferno's section on growing objects](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) is always a fun read for better understanding this.

Comment: also thanks zack! Thats quite a bit of reading looks like I have to do something this afternoon :D

Comment: Happy to help! And thanks, @zack - fair point. Don't forget to upvote and accept!